# Apache Airflow does not pickle DAGs

Tags: airflow

I would like to recover DAG objects so that I can better inspect certain dependencies after DAG runs (e.g. what data is consumed by specific operators). I am using `postgres:9.6` as metadata database backend.

This seems to be supported via the `donot_pickle` configuration variable, which by default indicates all DAGs must be pickled:

```
[core]
# Whether to disable pickling dags
donot_pickle = False
```

I have some test DAGs (3) available but their corresponding `pickle_id` is empty:

```
> select pickle_id from dag;
pickle_id
---------


(3 rows)
```

Pickles table is also empty:

```
> select count(*) from dag_pickle;
 count
------
    0
(1 row)
```

What might be going wrong here? I was not able to find any reference in the docs.

Answer (score 5):

There are 2 ways to enable pickling:

- `DONT_PICKLE=False` in scheduler config is only relevant for backfill jobs
- `-p, -do_pickle` in scheduler command line arguments enables pickling for scheduled jobs (https://airflow.apache.org/cli.html#Named%20Arguments_repeat18)