# Python 3.6 airflow with a Operator that requires 2.7

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-dataflow, airflow

I'm currently running an airflow (1.9.0) instance on python 3.6.5. I have a manual workflow that I'd like to move to a DAG. This manual workflow now requires code written in python 2 and 3. Let's simplify my DAG to 3 steps:

1. Dataflow job that processes data and sets up data for Machine
   Learning Training
2. Tensorflow ML training job
3. Other
   PythonOperators that I wrote using python 3 code

The dataflow job is written in python 2.7 (required by google) and the tensorflow model code is in python 3. Looking at "MLEngineTrainingOperator" in airflow 1.9.0 there is a python_version parameter which sets the "The version of Python used in training".

Questions:

- Can I dynamically specify a specific python version in a worker
  environment?
- Do I have to just install airflow on python 2.7 to make step 1) run?
- Can I have tensorflow model code in python 3 that just gets packaged up and submitted via MlEngineTraining running on python 2?
- Do I have to rewrite my 3) operators in python 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a way specify the python version dynamically on a worker. However if you are using the the Celery executor, you can run multiple workers either on difference servers/vms or in different virtual environments.

You can have one worker running python 3, and one running 2.7, and have each listening to different queues.  This can be done three different ways:

- When starting the worker you can add a `-q [queue-name]` flag
- set an env of `AIRFLOW__CELERY__DEFAULT_QUEUE`
- updating `default_queue` under `[celery]` in the airflow.cfg.

Then in your task definitions specify a `queue` parameter, changing the queue up depending on which python version the task needs to run.

I'm not familiar with the MLEngineOperator, but you can specify a `python_version` in the PythonOperator which should run it in a virtualenv of that version.  Alternative you can use the BashOperator, write the code to run in a different file and specify the python command to run it using the absolute path the version of python you want to use.

Regardless of how the task is run, you just need to ensure the DAG itself is compatible with python version you are running it as it. ie. if you are going to start an airflow worker in different python versions, the DAG file itself needs to be python 2 & 3 compatible. The DAG can have addition file dependencies that it uses have version incompatibilities.

Comment: So the MLEngineTrainingOperator never actually calls any python just an http request with the python module. However, the DataFlowPythonOperator inherits from the BaseOperator and uses the DataFlowHook which calls start_python_dataflow which has no notion of different python versions. I think the different celery workers seems like the way to go

Comment: From https://airflow.apache.org/configuration.html#setting-up-a-backend: "Operators that are executed on the worker need to have their dependencies met in that context. For example, if you use the HiveOperator, the hive CLI needs to be installed on that box, or if you use the MySqlOperator, the required Python library needs to be available in the PYTHONPATH somehow"... so does the how airflow library run on both python 2 and 3? Am I going to have to work with some operators in python 2 that have different code than python 3?

Comment: I guess you're saying I'm going to have to explicitly prepare for this... I'm just wondering if most or all of the airflow operators out of the box runs on both python 2 and 3...

Comment: Runn my dag in python 2 is currently giving me: "  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/sqltypes.py", line 1588, in process
    return loads(value)
ValueError: unsupported pickle protocol: 4
"

Comment: Most operators will work with 2 or 3.  I'd recommend running airflow under python 3.  Then you can either use the `PythonVirtualenvOperator` (https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/e9babff4eb3334b0d71cda31c2f6cbfe7b741389/airflow/operators/python_operator.py#L200) or setup your workers to have Python 2 installed but not in your path, and then use the `BashOperator` specifying the absolute path to python 2. (ie `/path/to/python2 /path/to/your_code_that_requires_py2`) to execute the script in Py2.

Answer (score 1):

Alright out of the box you cannot run a python 2 airflow worker on a general python 3 airflow cluster:

Airflow uses SQLAlchemy (I believe to read and write metadata about DAGs to the database). When you run a DAG on a worker it will read pickled information about that DAG from the DB. If your other non-worker components are in python 3 they will write to the DB in pickle 4 while the worker will try and read from the DB in python 2.

In particular look in SQLAlchemy look at sqltypes.py:

```
class PickleType(TypeDecorator):
    """Holds Python objects, which are serialized using pickle.

    PickleType builds upon the Binary type to apply Python's
    ``pickle.dumps()`` to incoming objects, and ``pickle.loads()`` on
    the way out, allowing any pickleable Python object to be stored as
    a serialized binary field.

    To allow ORM change events to propagate for elements associated
    with :class:`.PickleType`, see :ref:`mutable_toplevel`.

    """

    impl = LargeBinary

    def __init__(self, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL,
                 pickler=None, comparator=None):
```

and then in compat.py that ultimately does the pickling in sqltypes.py.

```
py36 = sys.version_info >= (3, 6)
py33 = sys.version_info >= (3, 3)
py35 = sys.version_info >= (3, 5)
py32 = sys.version_info >= (3, 2)
py3k = sys.version_info >= (3, 0)
py2k = sys.version_info < (3, 0)
py265 = sys.version_info >= (2, 6, 5)
jython = sys.platform.startswith('java')
pypy = hasattr(sys, 'pypy_version_info')
win32 = sys.platform.startswith('win')
cpython = not pypy and not jython  # TODO: something better for this ?

import collections
next = next

if py3k:
    import pickle
else:
    try:
        import cPickle as pickle
    except ImportError:
        import pickle
```

Also donot_pickle = True in airflow does not seem to have an impact on this??? Maybe because according to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48786437/apache-airflow-does-not-pickle-dags) it is only relevant in backfills?